# file permission to use yii constructor

Tags: php, yii, constructor

im new to yii.
i have my project and i need to use constructor to my controller
i used this

```
public function __construct($id, $module = null)
{
    ....
    ....
    $this->fee_main = 0;
    $this->fee_sub = 0;
    $this->fee_loket = 1; //100%
    require("soap/nusoap.php");
    parent::__construct($id, $module);
}
```

but when i upload to my server, the page i access (?r=xxx/yyy) just show white blank

im afraid it is because my file permission on server.
im just modify runtime folder to 777
so can anybody tell me what file permission and its path i must modify??

==UPDATE==

after i look deeper into code, it seems like it will be like this (error) every time i access function from component

Comment: You can't use constructor in controller. You can use init() method in it instead of constructor. constructor is reserved for yii controller.

Comment: i use init before but get some error,,is it because file permission?

Comment: i don't think it is because of file permission. add at top error_reporting(E_ALL); in your index.php file. show me the errors

Comment: If possible share link here.

Comment: mr yatin, i have update my question...

Comment: enable error_reporting(E_ALL); and defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true); in your index.php file

Comment: like this?<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Comment: see my ans and place in your index.php file and let me the what is the errror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(E_ALL); // add this in your index.php
  // change the following paths if necessary 
   $yii=dirname(FILE).'/framework/yii.php'; 
   $config=dirname(FILE).'/protected/config/main.php'; 

  // remove the following lines when in production mode 
   defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true); 

   // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message 
   defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
   require_once($yii); Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
?>
```

Comment: i got log like this,..
2015/07/08 08:25:25 [error] [php] Non-static method Funct::cLink() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context (/opt/lampp/htdocs/tiket/protected/views/layouts/main.php:95)
sorry,im new to yii

Comment: Do you have Funct component? then show method cLink() in your question

Comment: yeah, my bad, im not added it to my question,but thanks to u sir, now i can fix my code,..thankyou

Comment: remove your second screenshot it is showing your live url.